# jQuery is not working on Element class click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, event-handling

Following script is not working on my HTML page, any suggestions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.nf-next-item').click(function() {
        $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
        $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
    });
});
```

Jquery is also added in the file.(`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>`)

Following is the HTML code, it is in the .php file(actually it is a wordpress theme):

```
<div class="sidebar-header">
            <div class="step-1 displayBlock">
                <h2 class="formTitle"> <?php the_field('title_step_1') ?></h2>
                <h3> <?php the_field('text_step_1') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step-2 displayNone">
                <h2 class="formTitle"><?php the_field('title_step_2') ?></h2>
                <h3> <?php the_field('text_step_2') ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please ass a snippet with your code.

Comment: Can you paste html code?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct.  Make sure you have jquery included in the HTML and all the class names are correct.

Comment: What is "not working"? It is better to make that a little more specific :)

Comment: I just added the HTML code in the question, please check.

Comment: Where is your button with class "nf-next-item"? Put an alert inside the click function and see if it fires...

Comment: Also you should learn how to [include scripts in Wordpress.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) Is there a reason you ship a custom jquery with your theme?

Comment: Where are you placing this code? If it's wordpress you have to embed it using `wp_enqueue_script()` and specify `jquery` in deps array (third param). Also,  you have to wrap your jquery script in: `(function($){/* your code here */})(jQuery);` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */})`.

Comment: Do you see an error on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the elements you're trying to bind events to have not yet been added to markup by the time you're doing the binding.

In order to fix this, you should wrap to any ancestor of the elements that exists in the page at the time you're running the script.

For example:

```
$('.sidebar-header').on('click', 'li.nf-next-item', function(){
  $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
  $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
})
```

You could also wrap the entire code in a function, check if the element you're binding to exists and, if not, wait some time and run the function again. Example:

```
function binderCallback() {
  $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
  $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
}
function scriptBinder() {
  if ($('.sidebar-header').is('.sidebar-header')) {
    $('.sidebar-header').on('click', 'li.nf-next-item', binderCallback);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {scriptBinder()}, 1000);
  }
}
$(() => { scriptBinder() });
```

However, this construct is potentially dangerous and should be avoided as if, for any reason, the element you're waiting on is never added to the page, your script will continue calling itself forever. One safety measure around this is to place an iterator in the function and only allow it to call itself a finite number of times. Example which quits trying to bind after 10 attempts, made at intervals of 1 second:

```
let binderCounter = 0, 
    binderCallback = function() {
      $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
      $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
    };

function scriptBinder() {
  if ($('.sidebar-header').is('.sidebar-header')) {
    $('.sidebar-header').on('click', 'li.nf-next-item', binderCallback);
  } else {
    if (binderCounter++ < 10)
      setTimeout(() => {scriptBinder()}, 1000);
  }
}
$(() => { scriptBinder() });
```

Another alternative to the above is to bind on an element that you are certain exists when you do the binding. Like `<body>`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'li.nf-next-item', function(){
  $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
  $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
})
```

While the above will surely work (as long as your `li.nf-next-item` is correct, of course), it's less than optimal.
As stated in their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance):

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of `document` or `document.body` for delegated events on large documents.

Comment: Hi, following code is working:
        `$('body').on('click', 'li.nf-next-item', function() {
            $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
            $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
        });`

but for the input type button class it is not working: 
        `$('body').on('click', 'input.nf-next', function() {
            $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
            $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
        });`

Would you please suggest!

Comment: That can only mean a) you're not correctly selecting the input or b) that input has stronger applying CSS for `display` property and you need to override it. You could use `.displayNone:not(#_){display:none}` in your CSS. Same for `.displayBlock`. Inspect the elements in a browser to see what selector display is coming from, so you know how strong you need to make yours. You can inflate the specificty by chaining `:not()` selectors: `selector:not(#_):not(#_) {}` will override `#a #b selector {}` if placed later in code. Most importantly: do not use `!important`. It's a can of worms.

Comment: Another possible reason why the click doesn't fire might be the click event is prevented from bubbling (propagating) by other code applying to any element between the child and the parent you bound on (`body`). The condition for delegated bindings to work is that no element between the child receiving the event and the parent you bind on does not stop event propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. Without a [mcve] it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Yes, the event is preventing by other event applied to the same element. Is there a way to handle it. Following is the HTML code:
`<div class="nf-mp-footer"><div> 
 <ul class="nf-next-previous">
  <li class="nf-next-item">
   <input class="nf-next" value="Continue" type="button">
  </li>  
 </ul>
</div></div>`
It a Ninja Form Next button, on Button clicking it is going to the Next Step, I need to trigger my jQuery function along with ongoing functions.

Comment: In that case your only options are: make your binding directly on the button after it has been added to DOM (use the example with setTimeout to check but look for the button instead of parent - not optimal but does the trick) or read through the form provider's documentation if they have any means of running code when the form was added to the page (a callback method).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses, finally I got it solved with the following jQuery scripts: 
`function binderCallback() {
        $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
        $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".nf-next").attr("onclick", "binderCallback()");
        }, 5000);
    });` 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$('li.nf-next-item').on('click', function() {
    $(".step-1").removeClass('displayBlock').addClass('displayNone');
    $(".step-2").removeClass('displayNone').addClass('displayBlock');
});
```

It's better to use `.on` because uses less memory and works with dynamically added elements.

Comment: It only works with dynamically added elements if you delegate the binding to a parent that exists in DOM when you run the above code. But you're not delegating the binding. Your syntax is still binding to existing `li.nf-next-item` s that exist in page when you run the above.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the html for button or li on which you are applying the click.?

Check if `li.nf-next-item` is an `li` element & this class (`nf-next-item`) is added onto that `li` element. If that's a button, will not work.

And if it is a dynamic element which is getting added later, you probably do this `$('body').on('click', 'li.nf-next-item', function() {` instead of `$('li.nf-next-item').click(function() {` .. And it should work.